# White background on panel and all its children

Tags: xaml, background, panel, opacity

I have a StackPanel in my window. I want the stack panel to have a 0.8 opacity and a white layer over it.

This is my current code:

```
<Style x:Key="BackgroundStackStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Panel}">
        <!--<Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.8"></Setter>-->
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <SolidColorBrush Opacity="0.8" Color="White"></SolidColorBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I have some buttons on the stack panel. When I apply the style on that stack panel, the background of the panel has opacity and becomes white, and the buttons don't. They stay as they were previously.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You would have to put the StackPanel into another panel (e.g. a Grid) and add a white semi-transparent rectangle above it. Maybe you could also set the StackPanel's Background to a fully opaque white background and its total Opacity to 0.8.

Comment: I posted an answer a few seconds ago. Now that I think of it, your mistake is that you set the opacity on the background.
Just add a setter for the property Opacity, as I did in my example, and your buttons will have the same opacity as the stack panel

Comment: @Miiite You can see in the question that I've tried your solution (the commented code) and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describes, is actually supposed to work with the buttons.
Here's what I did as a test, and my buttons have a 0.5 opacity as expected. Maybe it can help you:

```
...<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Margin="20">
        <Button Content="button1" />
        <Button Content="button2" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>...
```